# Polymer automatically parse paper-input to number?

Tags: google-maps, parsing, polymer

In my Polymer project, I have a `<google-map>` with longitude and latitude value as properties. Underneath the map are two `<paper-input>` where the user can alternatively write the long and lat value for the map. When moving the cursor at the map, those two values update perfectly, however, when I write something in them, the map does not update. I assume it's because the `<paper-input>` puts the value as a string out and the map requires numbers as longitude & latitude value. Is there a simple way to automatically parse the value from `<paper-input>` to a number?

My Code:

```
<dom-module id="web-map">

<template>

 <google-map latitude="{{lat}}" longitude="{{long}}" style="height: 80%" id="map"></google-map>

<div style="width: 100%" align="center">
    <paper-input label="longitude" value="{{long::input}}" auto-validate="true" pattern="[-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*" error-message="Please enter a correct longitude value!" style="display: inline-block"></paper-input>
    <paper-input label="latitude" value="{{lat::input}}" auto-validate="true" pattern="[-]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*" error-message="Please enter a correct latitude value!" style="display: inline-block"></paper-input>
</div>

</template>

<script>

Polymer({
    is: "web-map",
    properties: {
        long: {
            type: Number,
            notify: true,
            value: -122.41942
        },
        lat: {
            type: Number,
            notify: true,
            value: 37.77493
        }
    }
});

</script>

</dom-module>
```

Comment: try removing ::input from the value

Comment: It seems to work here, although the inputs are finnicky, if you type in a number, it does move the map https://jsfiddle.net/6mby224g/1/

Comment: I removed the ::input, but it still doesn't work

Comment: try Computed Properties/Bindings for long and lat: 
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#computed-properties
 In the computing function do the casting: long = Number( value )

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue a while back, did a lil research and found that using "value-as-number" instead of "value" did the trick.

Comment: Please add sources